# Tasks API 403 Access Forbidden

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-tasks-api

```
03-30 15:20:53.422: W/System.err(25384):       "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
```

I get this error when trying to do a GET on Taskslist.

```
GoogleAccountCredential  credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, TasksScopes.all());

SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String accountName = settings.getString(GoogleIntegrationUtilities.GTASK_ACCOUNT_NAME, "None");
// assume accountname is always defined properly
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
tasksServiceBuilder = new Tasks.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("App name");
tasksService = tasksServiceBuilder.build();
```

In developer console, Tasks API is enabled with 0% usage. In credentials, I have an OAuth2 Client ID for Android application defined with SHA1 as from debug.keystore and package name defined.

Am I missing something? I've also gotten a permissions popup in my app, which I accepted - but it doesn't show up in https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the SHA1 of the debug.keystore was in lowercase in the dev console. Deleting that client ID and creating a new one with the SHA1 in uppercase solved the problem.